# salesforce contact social linking - linkedin profile image not visible

Tags: social-contacts

I am trying to display the linkedin profile image of a contact (linkedin authentication already done) on a visualforce page using PhotoUrl field of contact mentioned [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm).

While on the salesforce Contact detail page the image is getting displayed but its not showing up on my custom VF page. If I link facebook or Twitter, those profile images are showing up fine in my VF page.

Even though the linkedin module is labelled Beta, I just wanted to check if anybody else is also getting this issue or if there is something that I am not doing correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The LinkedIn for Salesforce beta has ended so even if you were able to surface information before you will not be able to do so until Salesforce and LinkedIn decide to work together again.  Here's a link to the help that [discusses the beta](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000227237&language=en_US)